# "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null" when using regex match in cheerio webscraping

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, cheerio

I want to scrape what is in brackets from this html:

```html
<dl class="ooa-1o0axny ev7e6t84">
  <dd class="ooa-16w655c ev7e6t83">
    <p class="ooa-gmxnzj">Cekcyn (Kujawsko-pomorskie)</p>
  </dd>
  <dd class="ooa-16w655c ev7e6t83">
    <p class="ooa-gmxnzj">Some other text</p>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

So I'm using (trying to use) regex (few different, doesn't matter) for example:

```js
$(item[x]).find('.ooa-gmxnzj:first').text().match(/(?<=\().*(?=\))/)[0]
```

And it's working, because i'm getting string from brackets, but right after i'm getting also an error:

```
$(item[x]).find('.ooa-gmxnzj:first').text().match(/(?<=\().*(?=\))/)[0]                                                                                                                   
                                                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')
```

I checked that what i'm getting in response is an array, and  console.log for same request, just without setting element array index, it's look like array with one element:

```js
[
  'Kujawsko-pomorskie',
  index: 8,
  input: 'Cekcyn (Kujawsko-pomorskie)',
  groups: undefined
]
```

I'm using axios and cheerio.
Could someone explain me why i'm getting error about null value, from array created by .match function??

When I use .slice() on same html code, there is no problem with reading all elements of array, without any error.

Comment: What output are you expecting? If you're just trying to parse the text inside an element and Cheerio is successfully returning the string of the text you expect, Cheerio is totally out of the picture and it's just a pure regex issue, so you can [edit] your post to remove the Cheerio aspect in the interests of a [mcve].

Comment: How about `"Cekcyn (Kujawsko-pomorskie)".match(/\((.*)\)/)[1]`? If `.text()` isn't returning what you expect, then it's not really a regex problem and we'd have to see the full structure and site to help.

Comment: `"Cekcyn (Kujawsko-pomorskie)".match(/\((.*)\)/)[1]` - it's working without error
`$(item[x]).find('.ooa-gmxnzj:first').text().match(/\((.*)\)/)[1]` - it's recognizing text properly, and it's giving me a answer, but same as before, its thrownig an error after that, "...properties of null"
`$(item[x]).find('.ooa-gmxnzj:first').text()` - result is: string `Cekcyn (Kujawsko-pomorskie)`

Comment: Thanks for the info. What you say doesn't seem consistent. If that Cheerio code is returning text that always matches the pattern you've provided, then there should be no "properties of null" error, which happens when the match fails. Is it possible that you're running the code on multiple inputs, and some don't have the parentheses structure the regex assumes? I'll need the actual website to be able to help.

Comment: I aggree that it sounds unconsistent, thats why i don't know what is happening.
Site is: [Link](https://www.otomoto.pl/osobowe/toyota/avensis/seg-combi?search%5Bfilter_enum_fuel_type%5D=petrol&search%5Bfilter_enum_gearbox%5D=manual&search%5Bfilter_enum_generation%5D=gen-iii-2009&search%5Bfilter_enum_heated_seat_driver%5D=1&search%5Bfilter_enum_heated_seat_passenger%5D=1&search%5Border%5D=created_at_first%3Adesc&search%5Badvanced_search_expanded%5D=true)

This is a car sales website. And I want to extract information about each offer.

Comment: and key parts of code:
`const $ = await cheerio.load(axiosResponse.data)
const item = $('main article')
(then for loop to go throu each offer, and save info to object)
const offer = {
            title: $(item[x]).find('.ev7e6t89.ooa-1xvnx1e.er34gjf0').text(),
            otomotoScore: $(item[x]).find('.e1xj1nw30.ooa-77y3u4.er34gjf0').text(),
            price: parseFloat($(item[x]).find('.ev7e6t82.ooa-bz4efo.er34gjf0').text().replace(/\s/g, '')),
            year: parseFloat($(item[x]).find('dd[data-parameter="year"]').text()),
`

Comment: `milage: parseFloat($(item[x]).find('dd[data-parameter="mileage"]').text().replace(/\s/g, '')),
            petrol: $(item[x]).find('dd[data-parameter="fuel_type"]').text(),
            city: $(item[x]).find('.ooa-gmxnzj').text().split(' (')[0],
            voivodeship: $(item[x]).find('.ooa-gmxnzj:first').text()
            dealer: $(item[x]).find('.ooa-kykccx.eyn0uzw1').attr('href'),
            link: $(item[x]).find('h1 a').attr('href')
        }
//console.log($(item[x]).find('.ooa-gmxnzj:first').text())
and at the end I'm pushing this object to array.
`

Comment: And the error comes when I try to extract the name of the voivodeship from a string that looks like: "name of the city (voivodeship)"

Comment: Please [edit] the post to show this update--it's really hard to make sense of code in the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those CSS selectors look a bit dynamic, so here's an approach that uses plain tags and pulls down 32 results:

```js
const axios = require("axios"); // 1.4.0
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "<Your URL>";

axios
  .get(url)
  .then(({data: html}) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const data = [...$("article dd > p")]
      .map(e => $(e).text().match(/(.*?) *\((.*)\)/))
      .filter(Boolean)
      .map(e => e.slice(1, 3));
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

In case you want to pull down more data than just this one field:

```js
axios
  .get(url)
  .then(({data: html}) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const data = [...$("main > div > article")]
      .map(e => ({
        something: $(e).find("dd > p")
          .text()
          .match(/(.*?) *\((.*)\)/)
          .slice(1, 3),
        price: $(e).find("h3").text().trim(),
        model: $(e).find("h1").text().trim(),
        mileage: $(e).find('[data-parameter="mileage"]')
          .text().trim(),
        fuelType: $(e).find('[data-parameter="fuel_type"]')
          .text().trim(),
      }));
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

To be clear, you *can* use CSS selectors if you feel they'll be stable--the fundamental strategy is basically the same. Start by selecting containers, which are `<article>`s, then dip into children to collect the data for that item.

I used `something` because I don't know what that field means in English.

Comment: Thats right, it's is a "bit dynamic" not to much. it was working at least month, but then they decide to change a bit UI layout, so I wanted to fit in.
Thanks @ggorlen, Maybe I'll go the way you suggest